# HttpWebResponse don't allow popUp

Tags: c#, asp.net, popup, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I making HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse and when i  get response i get error ->

An Add-on for this Website failed to run. Click Security Setting in the Internet Options for Potential conflicts.

I can't just press allow popUps from website i need to program this, enable popUp or add registry keys to this website.

Here my code

```
   string   postData += "userid=" + strUser + "&";
            postData += "numID=" + strUserId + "&";
            postData += "userPassword=" + strPass + "&";

            HttpWebRequest postRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(loginPostUrl);
            postRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            postRequest.CookieContainer = _cookies;
            postRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
            postRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0";
            postRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
            postRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
            postRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            postRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";



            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
            postRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream newStream = postRequest.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
            newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
            newStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse postResponseAfterLogin = (HttpWebResponse)postRequest.GetResponse();


            //After inserting User and Password
            Stream streamResponseLoginForm = postResponseAfterLogin.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader streamReadLoginForm = new StreamReader(streamResponseLoginForm);
            outString = streamReadLoginForm.ReadToEnd();//This is afer login btn pressed here we
```

I tried to login with WatIn

using (var browser = new IE("www.blabla.com"))
        {

```
        browser.TextField(Find.ById("userID")).Value = strUser;
        browser.TextField(Find.ById("numID")).Value = strUserId;
        browser.TextField(Find.ById("userPassword")).Value = strPass;

        browser.Image(Find.ById("inputSend")).Click();

        Thread.Sleep(WaitTime+2000);

    }
```

This not work to.I see this popUp the IE does't allow popUp from website www.blabla.com"

How to allow popup from website or and my website www.blabla.com" to list of websites that allow popup ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to internet options -> Privacy -> and uncheck Turn On POPUP and save.

As your Activex controls are get installed You have to allow them by this methopd only.

Comment: You are saing there is no way to this this in c#?I can't build program that forsed  user to do this by him self

Comment: U have to add your website to trusted website list....You cannot do it in coding...If its possible then everyone will be able to modify the computers registry keys which is defined as virus program(automatically executes without user permission)...